# Does std::reverse have redundant operations?

Tags: c++, algorithm, optimization

I'm about to go where no man has gone before, by challenging the `<algorithm>` library.

According to cplusplus.com, its implementation is equivalent to

```
template <class BidirectionalIterator>
  void reverse (BidirectionalIterator first, BidirectionalIterator last)
{
  while ((first!=last)&&(first!=--last)) {
    std::iter_swap (first,last);
    ++first;
  }
}
```

Is this the optimal solution, though? The

```
(first!=last)&&(first!=--last)
```

is a red flag to me. If the `BidirectionalIterator` can be compared with `<`, then

```
while ( first < last ) iter::swap(first++,--last);
```

will have fewer operations. For example, suppose we have

```
int arr [] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::reverse(arr, arr+sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int));
```

The comparisons and increments involved in the two procedures are

1. `--last`
2. `++first`
3. `first!=last`
4. `first!=X` where `X` is the result of step 1
5. `A&&B` (the result implicitly checked whether non-zero) where `A` is the result of step 3 and `B` is the result of step 4

versus

1. `--last`
2. `first < A` where `A` is the result of step 1
3. `++first`

in my solution.

So, please explain to me why the C++ `reverse` algorithm is implemented the way it is.

Sincerely,
Mike Rowe Optimeiser

Comment: So, how would you implement operator< efficiently for containers other than vector ?

Comment: Why do you assume it's actually implemented that way? The code you posted is an example of one possible solution.

Comment: `If the BidirectionalIterator can be compared with <` it would be called `RandomAccessIterator`.

Comment: You can have specialization fro random access iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, do not even quote cplusplus.com here. It is a terrible site. Don't trust a word there.

If you are curious how particular algorithm is implemented in specific library, just check for yourself. For example, this is from gcc 4.8.3 (copied verbatim except for removal of empty lines):

```
  template<typename _BidirectionalIterator>
    inline void
    reverse(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last)
    {
      ;
      std::__reverse(__first, __last, std::__iterator_category(__first));
    }
```

And here is implementation for random acces iterator:

```
  template<typename _RandomAccessIterator>
    void
    __reverse(_RandomAccessIterator __first, _RandomAccessIterator __last,
       random_access_iterator_tag)
    {
      if (__first == __last)
 return;
      --__last;
      while (__first < __last)
 {
   std::iter_swap(__first, __last);
   ++__first;
   --__last;
 }
```

As you see, it uses `<`.

Here is the one for biderectional iterators:

```
  template<typename _BidirectionalIterator>
    void
    __reverse(_BidirectionalIterator __first, _BidirectionalIterator __last,
       bidirectional_iterator_tag)
    {
      while (true)
 if (__first == __last || __first == --__last)
   return;
 else
   {
     std::iter_swap(__first, __last);
     ++__first;
   }
    }
```

This one does double check.

Comment: That's a lot of bile for another site. Can you say that _all_ implementations look and behave like you have above? The stuff over at C++.com says the implementation is 'equivalent to' -- not identical. Observed behavior is what matters, not a specific implementation's highly-optimized version of the same.

Comment: @Dúthomhas, it is no secret that cpplusplus.com is full of straight mistakes, omissions and slight incorrections. Pretty well-admitted fact.

Comment: I, for one, don't think it's nearly as bad as people make it out to be. Every site of substantial size has errors, cplusplus.com is not, by far, one of the worst offenders.

Comment: I'm not too impressed by Circular Reasoning. Your 'fact' is made-up. Cplusplus.com isn't perfect, but unless you can prove all the horrible, two-faced errors there, you're paddling the wrong way up a creek with me.

Answer (score 0):

A bidirectional iterator interface does not provide less than/greater than relational operators. It only satisfies the equality/inequality operator requirements of a forward iterator, so code written strictly against a bidirectional iterator interface cannot utilize `operator<`.

You can understand why a bidirectional iterator cannot provide such relational operators by imagining a double-linked list. If the iterator only stores state such as a pointer to the list node, it would be able to go forwards and backwards but would not be able to have a meaningful notion of "less than" or "greater than" given only that state. To have sufficient information to provide a meaningful notion of "less than" or "greater than" would typically imply that we can already implement a random-access iterator which is a superset of the bidirectional interface.

That code you showed seems perfectly reasonable given the bidirectional iterator requirements. It would be the kind of code required to generalize it to work for a doubly-linked list, e.g., and not just random-access sequences like `vector` or `deque`. However, it is but one possible implementation, and there's nothing to stop a vendor from extending upon it further.

Of course, that also doesn't exclude a vendor from providing a version optimized for random-access iterators that do actually provide relational operators operators in addition to equality/inequality using iterator tags or type traits. Yet a strict bidirectional iterator version (the most generalized version) would need to avoid relational operators.